# how to run build codenameone builds?

Tags: codenameone

Ok, I ran some of the demos under the simular from eclipse.  Submitted a desktop build and got a jar.  Now how do I run the jar?  It doesn't seem
to be directly runnable.

Also, where should I have found this information instead of asking
a bonehead question here?

```
> Buildfile: G:\share\projects\eclipse\Charts Demo\build.xml
> 
> jar:
>         [echo] Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
>         [echo]            code size and wider device support
>         [copy] Copying 1 file to G:\share\projects\eclipse\Charts Demo\build\tmp
>        [javac] G:\share\projects\eclipse\Charts Demo\build.xml:147: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to
> build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
>        [javac] Compiling 25 source files to G:\share\projects\eclipse\Charts Demo\build\tmp
>        [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>        [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>        [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
>        [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>        [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>        [javac] Note: G:\share\projects\eclipse\Charts Demo\src\com\codename1\demos\charts\ChartDemosForm.java uses unchecked
> or unsafe operations.
>        [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>        [javac] 3 warnings
>          [jar] Building jar: G:\share\projects\eclipse\Charts Demo\dist\Charts Demo.jar
>        [javac] G:\share\projects\eclipse\Charts Demo\build.xml:171: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to
> build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds BUILD
> SUCCESSFUL Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, desktop build was supposed to return exe file for windows and dmg for Mac. Something might have gone wrong for you to get jar file.

You can find bunch of information on [How do I](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i.html) page and here's a [link](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-desktop-application-with-codename-one.html) to desktop build.

Another thing you can do is prefix your Google search with `https://www.codenameone.com`.

For example, search for desktop build like this: `https://www.codenameone.com desktop application`

I will also suggest you follow Codenameone [blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog.html), as new features, latest release and archive of many cool stuff released in the past are available there.

Comment: I added my build transcript to the question.  I see no signs of an exe

Comment: You should send build by Right-clicking on your project -> Codenameone -> Send Desktop Windows. Then follow up on your build status on the Codenameone dashboard https://www.codenameone.com/build-server.html

Comment: I think its possible @ddyer looked under the bin directory instead of on the build server URL you provided. The exe etc. should be there.